# how to specify multiple mavenRepo's in build.gradle?

Tags: maven, github, gradle

I would like to use multiple mavenRepo's in my build:

```
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo {
      url: "http://cloudant.github.io/cloudant-sync-eap/repository/" 
      url: 'https://github.com/snowch/sync-android-p2p/raw/master/repository/'
      }
  }
```

However, the build fails with an error similar to this:

```
> Could not find method mavenRepo() for arguments [...] on repository container.
```

How can I specify multiple mavenRepo's?

---

**Note:** I'm using an old version of gradle and therefore need to use the deprecated mavenRepo statement.

Comment: May I ask is there any reason why you cannot upgrade your Gradle?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The project I forked from is using the old version (1.1).  I'm trying to minimise the changes in my fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [Gradle 1.1 documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/1.1/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10613), you *should* be able to use the newer `url` attribute as follows:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'http://cloudant.github.io/cloudant-sync-eap/repository/' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/snowch/sync-android-p2p/raw/master/repository/' }
}
```

As [this Gradle discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/problem-in-using-multiple-maven-repositories-in-gradle/2295/4) mentions, you should only use one URL per `maven` block.